# Add menu page issues (permissions & position)

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, pages, admin-menu, permissions

OK, I have an issue with [Sidebar Generator Plugin](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/sidebar-generator.1.1.zip).

This plugin creates subpage called "Sidebars" in WP-Admin. The point is, it is created as a child of "Appearance" page.

And I don't want it here, I want "Sidebars" to be a subpage of my own Page named "my-page".

I have found this line in the plugin's code:

```
function admin_menu(){
    add_submenu_page('themes.php', 'Sidebars', 'Sidebars', 'manage_options', __FILE__, array('sidebar_generator','admin_page'));
}
```

And changed 'themes.php' to 'my-page'.

Now "Sidebars" is being displayed under My-Page, but when I try to access it it shows:

> You do not have sufficient permissions
>   to access this page.

Why does it happen and how to fix that?

And additional question - the Sidebars subpage displays always at the top of my list of My-Page subpages, how to change that (in fact I want it to be the last subpage of My-Page).

Original, full code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Sidebar Generator
Plugin URI: http://www.getson.info
Description: This plugin generates as many sidebars as you need. Then allows you to place them on any page you wish. Version 1.1 now supports themes with multiple sidebars. 
Version: 1.1.0
Author: Kyle Getson
Author URI: http://www.kylegetson.com
Copyright (C) 2009 Kyle Robert Getson
*/

/*
Copyright (C) 2009 Kyle Robert Getson, kylegetson.com and getson.info

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

class sidebar_generator {

    function sidebar_generator(){
        add_action('init',array('sidebar_generator','init'));
        add_action('admin_menu',array('sidebar_generator','admin_menu'));
        add_action('admin_print_scripts', array('sidebar_generator','admin_print_scripts'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_add_sidebar', array('sidebar_generator','add_sidebar') );
        add_action('wp_ajax_remove_sidebar', array('sidebar_generator','remove_sidebar') );

        //edit posts/pages
        add_action('edit_form_advanced', array('sidebar_generator', 'edit_form'));
        add_action('edit_page_form', array('sidebar_generator', 'edit_form'));

        //save posts/pages
        add_action('edit_post', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));
        add_action('publish_post', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));
        add_action('save_post', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));
        add_action('edit_page_form', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));

    }

    function init(){
        //go through each sidebar and register it
        $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();


        if(is_array($sidebars)){
            foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
                $sidebar_class = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($sidebar);
                register_sidebar(array(
                    'name'=>$sidebar,
                    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget sbg_widget '.$sidebar_class.' %2$s">',
                    'after_widget' => '</li>',
                    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle sbg_title">',
                    'after_title' => '</h2>',
                ));
            }
        }
    }

    function admin_print_scripts(){
        wp_print_scripts( array( 'sack' ));
        ?>
            <script>
                function add_sidebar( sidebar_name )
                {

                    var mysack = new sack("<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" );    

                    mysack.execute = 1;
                    mysack.method = 'POST';
                    mysack.setVar( "action", "add_sidebar" );
                    mysack.setVar( "sidebar_name", sidebar_name );
                    mysack.encVar( "cookie", document.cookie, false );
                    mysack.onError = function() { alert('Ajax error. Cannot add sidebar' )};
                    mysack.runAJAX();
                    return true;
                }

                function remove_sidebar( sidebar_name,num )
                {

                    var mysack = new sack("<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" );    

                    mysack.execute = 1;
                    mysack.method = 'POST';
                    mysack.setVar( "action", "remove_sidebar" );
                    mysack.setVar( "sidebar_name", sidebar_name );
                    mysack.setVar( "row_number", num );
                    mysack.encVar( "cookie", document.cookie, false );
                    mysack.onError = function() { alert('Ajax error. Cannot add sidebar' )};
                    mysack.runAJAX();
                    //alert('hi!:::'+sidebar_name);
                    return true;
                }
            </script>
        <?php
    }

    function add_sidebar(){
        $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
        $name = str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$_POST['sidebar_name']);
        $id = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($name);
        if(isset($sidebars[$id])){
            die("alert('Sidebar already exists, please use a different name.')");
        }

        $sidebars[$id] = $name;
        sidebar_generator::update_sidebars($sidebars);

        $js = "
            var tbl = document.getElementById('sbg_table');
            var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
            // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
            var iteration = lastRow;
            var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

            // left cell
            var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode('$name');
            cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

            //middle cell
            var cellLeft = row.insertCell(1);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode('$id');
            cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

            //var cellLeft = row.insertCell(2);
            //var textNode = document.createTextNode('[<a href=\'javascript:void(0);\' onclick=\'return remove_sidebar_link($name);\'>Remove</a>]');
            //cellLeft.appendChild(textNode)

            var cellLeft = row.insertCell(2);
            removeLink = document.createElement('a');
            linkText = document.createTextNode('remove');
            removeLink.setAttribute('onclick', 'remove_sidebar_link(\'$name\')');
            removeLink.setAttribute('href', 'javacript:void(0)');

            removeLink.appendChild(linkText);
            cellLeft.appendChild(removeLink);


        ";


        die( "$js");
    }

    function remove_sidebar(){
        $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
        $name = str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$_POST['sidebar_name']);
        $id = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($name);
        if(!isset($sidebars[$id])){
            die("alert('Sidebar does not exist.')");
        }
        $row_number = $_POST['row_number'];
        unset($sidebars[$id]);
        sidebar_generator::update_sidebars($sidebars);
        $js = "
            var tbl = document.getElementById('sbg_table');
            tbl.deleteRow($row_number)

        ";
        die($js);
    }

    function admin_menu(){
        add_submenu_page('themes.php', 'Sidebars', 'Sidebars', 'manage_options', __FILE__, array('sidebar_generator','admin_page'));
    }

    function admin_page(){
        ?>
        <script>
            function remove_sidebar_link(name,num){
                answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove " + name + "?\nThis will remove any widgets you have assigned to this sidebar.");
                if(answer){
                    //alert('AJAX REMOVE');
                    remove_sidebar(name,num);
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            function add_sidebar_link(){
                var sidebar_name = prompt("Sidebar Name:","");
                //alert(sidebar_name);
                add_sidebar(sidebar_name);
            }
        </script>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Sidebar Generator</h2>
            <p>
                The sidebar name is for your use only. It will not be visible to any of your visitors. 
                A CSS class is assigned to each of your sidebar, use this styling to customize the sidebars.
            </p>
            <br />
            <div class="add_sidebar">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return add_sidebar_link()" title="Add a sidebar">+ Add Sidebar</a>
            </div>
            <br />
            <table class="widefat page" id="sbg_table" style="width:600px;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>CSS class</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
                //$sidebars = array('bob','john','mike','asdf');
                if(is_array($sidebars) && !empty($sidebars)){
                    $cnt=0;
                    foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
                        $alt = ($cnt%2 == 0 ? 'alternate' : '');
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo $alt?>">
                    <td><?php echo $sidebar; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo sidebar_generator::name_to_class($sidebar); ?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return remove_sidebar_link('<?php echo $sidebar; ?>',<?php echo $cnt+1; ?>);" title="Remove this sidebar">remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                        $cnt++;
                    }
                }else{
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">No Sidebars defined</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
            <br /><br />
            <div class="donate">
                <h5>Donate</h5>
                <p>
                    Support the further development of this plugin.
                </p>
                <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="9271055">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * for saving the pages/post
    */
    function save_form($post_id){
        $is_saving = $_POST['sbg_edit'];
        if(!empty($is_saving)){
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar');
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement');
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar', $_POST['sidebar_generator']);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', $_POST['sidebar_generator_replacement']);
        }       
    }

    function edit_form(){
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post;
        if (is_object($post_id)) {
            $post_id = $post_id->ID;
        }
        $selected_sidebar = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar', true);
        if(!is_array($selected_sidebar)){
            $tmp = $selected_sidebar; 
            $selected_sidebar = array(); 
            $selected_sidebar[0] = $tmp;
        }
        $selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);
        if(!is_array($selected_sidebar_replacement)){
            $tmp = $selected_sidebar_replacement; 
            $selected_sidebar_replacement = array(); 
            $selected_sidebar_replacement[0] = $tmp;
        }
        ?>

    <div id='sbg-sortables' class='meta-box-sortables'>
        <div id="sbg_box" class="postbox " >
            <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br /></div><h3 class='hndle'><span>Sidebars</span></h3>
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="sbg_container">
                    <input name="sbg_edit" type="hidden" value="sbg_edit" />

                    <p>
                        Select the sidebar you wish to display on this page, and which sidebar it will replace. (leave unselected to use the default sidebar everywhere)
                    </p>
                    <ul>
                    <?php 
                    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
                    //var_dump($wp_registered_sidebars);        
                        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){ ?>
                            <li>Replace 
                            <select name="sidebar_generator[<?=$i?>]">
                                <option value="0"<?php if($selected_sidebar[$i] == ''){ echo " selected";} ?>>WP Default Sidebar</option>
                            <?php
                            $sidebars = $wp_registered_sidebars;// sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
                            if(is_array($sidebars) && !empty($sidebars)){
                                foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
                                    if($selected_sidebar[$i] == $sidebar['name']){
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}' selected>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}'>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                             with  
                            <select name="sidebar_generator_replacement[<?=$i?>]">
                                <option value="0"<?php if($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i] == ''){ echo " selected";} ?>>None</option>
                            <?php

                            $sidebar_replacements = $wp_registered_sidebars;//sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
                            if(is_array($sidebar_replacements) && !empty($sidebar_replacements)){
                                foreach($sidebar_replacements as $sidebar){
                                    if($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i] == $sidebar['name']){
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}' selected>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}'>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select> 

                            </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * called by the action get_sidebar. this is what places this into the theme
    */
    function get_sidebar($name="0"){
        if(!is_singular()){
            if($name != "0"){
                dynamic_sidebar($name);
            }else{
                dynamic_sidebar();
            }
            return;//dont do anything
        }
        global $wp_query;
        $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $selected_sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar', true);
        $selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);
        $did_sidebar = false;
        //this page uses a generated sidebar
        if($selected_sidebar != '' && $selected_sidebar != "0"){
            echo "\n\n<!-- begin generated sidebar -->\n";
            if(is_array($selected_sidebar) && !empty($selected_sidebar)){
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($selected_sidebar);$i++){                    

                    if($name == "0" && $selected_sidebar[$i] == "0" &&  $selected_sidebar_replacement[$i] == "0"){
                        //echo "\n\n<!-- [called $name selected {$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement {$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]}] -->";
                        dynamic_sidebar();//default behavior
                        $did_sidebar = true;
                        break;
                    }elseif($name == "0" && $selected_sidebar[$i] == "0"){
                        //we are replacing the default sidebar with something
                        //echo "\n\n<!-- [called $name selected {$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement {$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]}] -->";
                        dynamic_sidebar($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]);//default behavior
                        $did_sidebar = true;
                        break;
                    }elseif($selected_sidebar[$i] == $name){
                        //we are replacing this $name
                        //echo "\n\n<!-- [called $name selected {$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement {$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]}] -->";
                        $did_sidebar = true;
                        dynamic_sidebar($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]);//default behavior
                        break;
                    }
                    //echo "<!-- called=$name selected={$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement={$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]} -->\n";
                }
            }
            if($did_sidebar == true){
                echo "\n<!-- end generated sidebar -->\n\n";
                return;
            }
            //go through without finding any replacements, lets just send them what they asked for
            if($name != "0"){
                dynamic_sidebar($name);
            }else{
                dynamic_sidebar();
            }
            echo "\n<!-- end generated sidebar -->\n\n";
            return;         
        }else{
            if($name != "0"){
                dynamic_sidebar($name);
            }else{
                dynamic_sidebar();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * replaces array of sidebar names
    */
    function update_sidebars($sidebar_array){
        $sidebars = update_option('sbg_sidebars',$sidebar_array);
    }   

    /**
     * gets the generated sidebars
    */
    function get_sidebars(){
        $sidebars = get_option('sbg_sidebars');
        return $sidebars;
    }
    function name_to_class($name){
        $class = str_replace(array(' ',',','.','"',"'",'/',"\\",'+','=',')','(','*','&','^','%','$','#','@','!','~','`','<','>','?','[',']','{','}','|',':',),'',$name);
        return $class;
    }

}
$sbg = new sidebar_generator;

function generated_dynamic_sidebar($name='0'){
    sidebar_generator::get_sidebar($name);  
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: You have "javacript:void(0)" in your code (missing the 's').  I'd edit, but I don't have privileges here.

Comment: Try removing the sidebar from the plugin before you add it to your menu, using `remove_submenu_page`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
// create your own page
    add_menu_page('my-page', 'My Page', 'My Page', 'parent-slug', 'my_plugin_options', '', '10');

// create the subpage under my-page
    add_submenu_page('parent-slug', 'Sidebars', 'Sidebars', 'manage_options', __FILE__, array('sidebar_generator','admin_page'));
```

Note that the last parameter on add_menu_page is a 10.  The higher the number the lower the position of the menu item.

HTH

Comment: I already have a page defined in functions.php and want Sidebar to be it's subpage. So creating another page is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

With `add_menu_page` then you can use `position`
with `add_submenu_page` then you can use priority of `add_action( 'admin_menu', '...', $priority)`

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'function_to_create_menu_page');
add_action('admin_menu', 'function_to_create_submenu_1_page', 100);
add_action('admin_menu', 'function_to_create_submenu_2_page', 101);
add_action('admin_menu', 'function_to_create_submenu_3_page', 103);
```

Just change the last number (priority) to change position of submenu.